# Create a simple React library usable within a Sencha Ext JS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, extjs

What i have is an Extjs Application, what i need to do is, given a reactJs library, i need to add it to my Extjs application, and use it as a component.

the React Library is used this way in react:

```
import {ReactLibrary} from
"@spog/component_library/dist/Components/nav/index";
<ReactLibrary
                appsUrl={{
                 cloud_console: "https://www.example.com",
                 one_system: "https://example-dev4.example.com/",
                 uc: "https://www.example.com",
            portal: "Portal URL" //your key should match with appName returned from /user/apps API
                }}
                uccIconStyle={{
                position: "fixed",
                top: "10px",
                left: "5px",
                zIndex: +10000,
                color: 'white'
                }}
 appName="system-protection"
                name={"Oscar Soliz"}
                email={"oscar.asd012@gmail.com"}
 userName={“user_name” }
 ucBeURL= "https://www.example.com:8443/api"
              /
```

i have not too much expierience in React so i don't know how can instance it as a component or even a javascript.

I've been following this guide which is the only one i've found: https://hollyos.medium.com/react-in-extjs-ad3da5f2b8ab
the first step is to create the library which i skipped since i already have it,
the second step is to transpile the code using babel this i had no issue,
the third step is Using the library in a browser using a script tag,
it tells me to create a new index.html this puts a script, but since i don't know much about React it looks like is calling the library he created in that script so i think i need to do the same but based on my library
after that it install webpack so to wrap all into one file but when i run the webpack i get this error:
[error when packing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WK7F.png)

and here is where im stuck.